# Numerar consecutivamente a medida que se van insertando con triggers

Tags: trigger

como habéis leido como numerar consecutivamente las UF mientras se insertan (sin utilizar auto_increment) y utilizando triggers no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo sin hacer auto_increment y además con triggers, agradeceria una pequeña ayuda

```
use prog;

drop table if exists uf;
drop table if exists modulo;

create table modulo (
 num int primary key,
 titulo varchar(100) not null,
 horas int not null
);

create table uf (
 modulo_num int not null,
 uf_num int not null,
 titulo varchar(100) not null,
 horas int not null,
 primary key (modulo_num, uf_num),
 foreign key (modulo_num) references modulo(num) 
);

insert into modulo values
(1,'Sistemas operativos',165),
(2,'Bases de datos',192);
```

Comment: Genial que aportes el dataset, muchas gracias. Ahora intenta algo, aunque no funcione, e indica el SGBD, ¿MySQL?

Comment: Esta pregunta se nos ha duplicado, ¿no? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358849 Recuerda eliminar la incompleta para que no se quede por aquí sin respuesta